# Data visualization: Maps using ggplot2 and facet layout

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, data-visualization, facet

I would like to create a conditional micromap using `R`. Basically I would like to create a facet (grid layout) for four different variables in the example below p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2) and plot each states map with color coded 1 for blue and 0 for green.

Below is the sample code. The data that is to be used for color coding is "mydata", 0 for green and 1 for blow for each of the variable p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2 How would I accomplish this in using ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(scales) # for function alpha()
us.dat <- map_data("state")

ggplot(us.dat, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon(fill="grey65", colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none", text = element_blank(), line = element_blank()) + coord_map("polyconic") 

# create random data

states <- unique(us.dat$region)
p_1 <- sample(0:1,49,replace=T)
p_2 <- sample(0:1,49,replace = T)
q_1 <- sample(0:1,49,replace=T)
q_2 <- sample(0:1,49,replace = T)

mydata <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(states,p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2)))
```

The chart layout below is what I would like to accomplish with one common legend.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reformat your data so it is in long format with your variables identified by a key. Then you need to merge it with the spatial data. Then use `facet_wrap(~ key)` to create the four panels.

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
us.dat %>%
  dplyr::left_join(
    mydata %>% 
      tidyr::gather(key, value, -states),
    by = c("region" = "states")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group, fill = value),
               colour = alpha("white", 1/2), 
               size = 0.2) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(# legend.position = "none", 
        line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()
        ) + 
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  facet_wrap(~ key)
```

I added a few theme elements to get it to look similar to what you want.
You will need to use a `scale_fill_manual()` to get the colors you want.

Comment: User asked for one common legend, change `legend.position = "none"` to `legend.position = "top"`?

Comment: Right, I missed that part of the question. With `facet_wrap` only one legend is produced. I edited the answer to comment out the `legend.position` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. I get the following error when I join the table using your snippet, {Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector}, not sure why, since both states and region are char. From what I can see, you have joined the two tables, to create a long format correct ? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Converting to "long" format is done with `gather()`. Joining with the spatial data is necessary because anything you want to plot in ggplot needs to be in a single data frame. And what you see isn't an error, it's a warning. It is caused because `us.dat$region` is character and `mydata$states` is factor. An alternative would be to create your data frame without factors. dplyr's `data_frame()` function does this by default. E.g. `mydata <- dplyr::data_frame(states, p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2)`